# Is it difference between 0 and -0 in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to create a cycled linked list and I need to find max and min values in it, so I need some checkpoint to stop, and I want to do that with -0 in first element(it will be just a checkpoint not anything else).
I don't want to use any else value because user can input new data into the list, if user inputs -0 I will simply replace it on 0 because from math side it is no difference between them (I don't use eternally-small digits :) ).
I use integer values.

question is not profitable now.
I try it and the result is they are same:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    if(0 != -0){
        cout << "they are different!";
    }else{
        cout << "they are same";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: Is it that hard to check yourself?

Comment: With floating point values, there is a separate -0 and +0. However, they compare equal, so distinguishing between them will be tough.

Comment: I am really struggling to understand the question. It seems that you have a circular list of doubles, and you want to use the IEEE negative zero as a sentinel. Correct? If so, what exactly is the question?

Comment: @sftrabbit Distinguishing them isn't that tough, `1.0/0.0 > 1.0/-0.0`.

Comment: Is this a question about integers or floating point numbers?

Comment: @sftrabbit: Or use `signbit()`.

Comment: I use integer values.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that current C/C++ standards require the integer number system to *behave* as if it were 2s-complement for standard arithmetic.  (A little unclear as to whether 2s-complement is *required*, from a physical standpoint.)  But in any event, even if you can create a -0 value, it would be a Schroedinger's cat situation -- doing anything with it would be apt to change it to +0.

Comment: @sftrabbit You could do bar>>sizeof(float)-1

Answer (score 3):

As in maths `0` and `-0` are the same value. You can not differentiate them in any way and so you can use this condition as you describe it.

Comment: Well, you can differentiate between them if we're talking about sign-magnitude or one's-complement representations...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth true but then that would not be very portable.

Comment: In math exists concept of right and left bound in limits http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/calculus/limlr/limlr.html . so there is the difference between them. whatever I asking not about math but about C++.

Comment: It depends of the data type actually. If we talk about a float, there are two representation of 0, one positive and one negative, which don't have the same integer representations...

Comment: @JBL it is explicitly stated that OP uses integers.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Oops, indeed, my bad !

Comment: @user1761284 but what you mention in maths is not an integer it's simply a notation for left and right bound.

Answer (score 2):

Integer values in the nearly universal twos-complement system *can't* be negative zero - there's no representation for them. Negative zero simply doesn't exist.

Negative zero is possible with IEEE floating point numbers, but don't come about very often. Multiplying a negative number by 0.0 will do it.

I'd suggest finding another sentinel value.

Comment: Negative zeroes are not rare, and “normalization” of results does not typically convert a negative zero to a positive one. The IEEE-754 floating-point standard is specific about when operations return -0 and when operations return +0.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, it does seem to be easy to generate `-0.0` if you want, `-1.0*0.0` will do it according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero). So maybe they're not as rare as I thought. I still hardly ever come across one in the wild.

Comment: @MarkRansom - most of the time, programmers don't care about the difference. The only consequences I can think of at the moment are that 1.0/-0.0 goes to -infinity, and 1.0/0/0 goes to infinity, and that `signbit` can tell the difference (as @KitsuneYMG points out). Regardless, the code that does this has problems.

Comment: @PeteBecker, people care when the results are displayed. It's quite surprising to see `-0.0` and the product I work on had a bug opened on it for just that reason. The fact that it took years for it to be reported is why I asserted that they're rare.

Comment: @MarkRansom - good point. And they are rare, because they typically disappear in calculations.

Answer (score 1):

This would require you store ints as doubles, mind. But you could do something like this.

[signbit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit) probably does the trick. If not, try taking the reciprocal. 1/+0.0 = +inf, 1/-0.0 = -inf. As a last ditch effort, do something like:

```
double d=-0.0;
bool is_neg = (*(uint64_t*)&d)&0x8000000000000000;
```

Comment: `I use integer value` last part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use NaN as a checkpoint:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
struct cll {
  double value;
  cll * next;
};
int main() {
  int N = 5;
  double input[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  cll * first = new cll;
  first->value = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
  cll * next = first;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    cll * last = new cll;
    next->next = last;
    last->value = input[i];
    last->next = first;
    next = last;
  }
  next = next->next;
  next = next->next;
  while (next->value == next->value)  {
    next = next->next;
  }
  next = next->next;
  while (next->value == next->value) {
    std::cout << next->value << '\n';
    next = next->next;
  }
  return 0;
}
```